# How to insert the number from category name to WooCommerce product stock number?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Is it possible to get only the number from the category name (category = Shirt - 20) & I want '20' to insert it into the product stock number. Here it is inserting the number '999' now by this folowing code

```
<script>
        jQuery( function( $ ) {
            $('.post-type-product #product_catchecklist input[type=checkbox]').click( function () {
                //Check if post title is empty and if only one category is selected
                if( $('.post-type-product #product_catchecklist').find('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length === 1 && $('#_stock').val().length <= 1 ) {                  
                    //If so, add the category to the product stock
                    $('.post-type-product #product_catchecklist input[type=checkbox]').each(function(){                           
                        if (this.checked) {
                            let $category = $(this).closest('label').text();
                            $('label').html('');
                            $('#_stock').val(999);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It often happens that stock is often distributed between stockrooms and production floors. The problem is that tracking stock that is distributed across two locations.

Surprisingly, there is no built in solution for tracking distributed stock. I decided to create a custom solution that would involve custom fields. There will be two custom ‘factory stock’ field and the ‘total stock’.

The total stock field will contain the sum of the factory stock and the WooCommerce built in stock control. This is an easy way of tracking the total stock numbers even when they are actually distributed across two locations.

At the moment, this solution works for Simple Products but it could be expended to cover Variable Product as well. To make things even better, I have added two columns for these stock levels to the product list columns.

Add the following code to the functions.php file.

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_styles' );
function theme_enqueue_styles() {
wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );

}

add_action('admin_head', 'my_custom_fonts');

function my_custom_fonts() {
echo '<style>
._total_inventory_field {
        color: red;
    }
._total_inventory_field input {
background-color:red;
color: #fff;
}
</style>';
}

add_action('save_post', 'myWoo_savePost', 10, 2);

function myWoo_savePost($postID, $post) {
if (isset($post->post_type) && $post->post_type == 'product') {
$shopstock = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_stock', true);
$factorystock = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_factory_inventory', true);
$totalstock = $shopstock + $factorystock;
update_post_meta($post->ID, '_manage_stock', 'yes');
update_post_meta($post->ID, '_total_inventory', $totalstock);
}
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_inventory_product_data', 'woo_add_custom_general_fields' );

// Save Fields
add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'woo_add_custom_general_fields_save');

function woo_add_custom_general_fields() {

    global $woocommerce, $post;

echo '<div class="options_group">';

woocommerce_wp_text_input(
array(
'id' => '_factory_inventory',
'label' => __( 'Factory Inventory', 'woocommerce' ),
'description' => __( 'Please Enter Your Factory Count.', 'woocommerce' ),
'type' => 'number',
)
);
// Number Field
woocommerce_wp_text_input(
array(
'id' => '_total_inventory',
'label' => __( 'Total Inventory', 'woocommerce' ),
'placeholder' => "",
'description' => __( 'Stock Must Match.', 'woocommerce' ),
'type' => 'number',
'custom_attributes' => array(
'step' => 'any',
'min' => '0',
)
)
);
echo '</div>';

}
function woo_add_custom_general_fields_save( $post_id ){

$woocommerce_number_field = $_POST['_factory_inventory'];
if( !empty( $woocommerce_number_field ) )
update_post_meta( $post_id, '_factory_inventory', esc_attr( $woocommerce_number_field ) );
}


function add_custom_stock_values( $column ) {
$column['factory_stock'] = 'Factory Stock';
$column['total_stock'] = 'Total Stock';

return $column;
}
add_filter( 'manage_product_posts_columns', 'add_custom_stock_values');

function add_value_to_custom_stock( $column_name, $post_id ) {

    $custom_fields = get_post_custom( $post_id );

    switch ($column_name) {
        case 'factory_stock' :
echo $custom_fields['_factory_inventory'][0];
break;

        case 'total_stock' :
echo $custom_fields['_total_inventory'][0];
break;

        default:
    }
}

add_action( 'manage_product_posts_custom_column', 'add_value_to_custom_stock', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: what problem do you see?